# Accessing session from within socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

is it possible to access and modify session variables 
from the socket.io level?

Regular example from request

```
 req.session.variable = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this project to use session in socket.io

https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io

Or do it yourself :

Get the cookies from the handshakedata

```
socket.handshake.headers.cookie
```

Parse the cookie using cookie module

```
var cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie');
var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
```

The cookie is signed so you need to valid it first and then get the sessionID

```
var connect  = require('express/node_modules/connect');
var sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(cookies['connect.sid'], /*The secret you used in your express session*/);
```

Then you can load the session from your sessionstore

```
sessionStore.load(sessionID, function (err, session) {
                if (!err && session) {
                    //Here you have your session if everything ok
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have already managed to do that, but this is the correct answer so I will mark it as such.

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing for a long time. Your answer makes perfect sense however I made a couple of workarounds for the same.